# Preserve XML comments in iReport .jrxml files?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

When I save the XML file in iReport, all comments are deleted.

How can I include (or preserve) comments in JRXML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to [preserve comments](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/533023/comments-jrxml-are-erased-ireport); you'd have to log a bug against iReport.

You can work around the issue by using callouts:

```
<property
  name="ireport.callouts"
  value="##Fri Nov 12 23:12:35 GMT-03:00 2010\\ncallouts.1.text=Hello World!\\ncallouts.1.bounds=294,80,181,73"/>
```

Comment: Found it http://community.jaspersoft.com/ireport-designer/issues/822 please up vote it

Comment: No need of bu report, jasper has given callOut for the same

Answer (score 1):

If you can't save comments you an use CallOut component form the iReport, With CallOut you can write a comment. It's not a perfect solution but can help a lot in a case you want comments on raw report

Its V3.7+ feature, more details on-
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-v371-release-notes