# Adding Comments in JasperReports template (jrxml)

Tags: jasper-reports

How to add comments in *JasperReports* template file (*JRXML*). I need to add some comments in each band to describe the functionality of band and also the need to write some comments for sub reports. So how do I add comments to jrxml file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Preserve XML comments in iReport .jrxml files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15341057/876298)

Answer (score 8):

## Use Callouts feature in iReport Designer tool

---

Since *iReport 3.7.1* there is an element called **Callouts** added especially to cater to **comments** provision.

Go to *Window -> Pallete* menu in *iReport* designer. These "Callouts" works like sticky notes in the *iReport* interface and in the generated XML it looks like this:

```xml
<property name="ireport.callouts" value="##Mon Aug 12 18:03:15 MSK 2013\ncallouts.2.text=This is Detail band\ncallouts.1.text=This is Title Band\ncallouts.2.bounds=353,118,150,75\ncallouts.1.bounds=34,17,239,83"/>
```

In GUI designer (*iReport*) notes look like:

[image: Adding Callout in iReport]

---

For more details look at [comments in jrxml are erased by iReport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/533023/comments-jrxml-are-erased-ireport) post on http://community.jaspersoft.com

Comment: Repost from http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/533023/comments-jrxml-are-erased-ireport

Comment: yes! there is a post on jaspersoft community which discusses this problem in detail. Several people had varied thoughts in which the pertinent suggestion got concealed. So bringing it in focus again. Callouts is the standard way offered by iReport and if there is a standard way, why go for get arounds? @AlexK

Answer (score 5):

In earlier versions of *JasperReports* (*iReport*) do not have such built-in opportunities.

For example, we can use the *"custom properties"* mechanism for solving this issue.

In the sample below I'm showing how to add the property *Description* for field in *iReport*.

[image: Adding property with iReport]

For band we can add property manually (add line to *jrxml* file).

The sample of *jrxml* file with custom properties:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample_comments" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0dfb0d3b-8128-4f2d-b12a-9b5edac0f460">
    <property name="Desription" value="This is a sample of report with comments. The custom properties are used"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, city FROM address]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="Description" value="The identificator"/>
    </field>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="Description" value="Column header Band"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="8c120f11-e5bf-40e1-9234-3bcede068949" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c8c11f63-d12d-4fbf-b146-dc3d95071065" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[City]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="402fcbe3-ef31-475b-8d0f-9da66c3a0692" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                    <property name="Description" value="Contains the Id field"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="96bd13a6-a90e-46c6-8c43-ca45b2b7db1d" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

It this *jrxml* file I've added "comment" for field, *textField* and to the Band.

---

You can find alternative method in [Preserve XML comments in iReport .jrxml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341057/preserve-xml-comments-in-ireport-jrxml-files) post

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
```

will work in jrxml.

Comment: It doesn't work in some old version of *iReport* - the comments are removed by *iReport*

Comment: ok... i do it manually . i dont use ireport... Or you can use <description> tag.Though its not comment.but will still serve the purpose.and i hope ireport should not delete it. :D

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Jasper (0.6.0), I use simply create a parameter named "Comments" and use the parameterDescription to make my comments.

Here, I can add anything I like.
          My comments can be as long as I want
          and can span as many rows as I need.
          I could keep a chronological update history here if I wanted to.
          It's not as convenient as in-line commenting,
          but at least I don't have to worry about iReport removing
          my comments when it compiles.